# Python dictionary printing first word behaviour

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm learning python and am on the topic of dictionaries. I wrote the following dictionary:

```
Team={
    ('projectmanager','Asma'): 'Sara',
    ('ba','Richard'): 'Steve',
    ('tester','Asma'): 'Rob',
    'developer1': 'Misbah',
    'developer2': 'Mariam'
}
```

I then wrote the following code:

```
for k,v in Team.items():
    profile=type(k)
    print('engTeam => {1} {0}'.format(k[0][0],profile))
```

The output I get is:

```
Team => <class 'str'> e
Team => <class 'str'> d
Team => <class 'tuple'> i
Team => <class 'str'> m
Team => <class 'tuple'> b
Team => <class 'str'> s
Team => <class 'tuple'> p
Team => <class 'str'> e
Team => <class 'str'> a
```

I don't understand why the first character of all non-tuple entries are being printed. If I think about it `k[0][0]` in my mind means get me the first element of the dictionary then the first sub element. But the non-tuple words don't have a sub element so the output should be blank, shouldn't it? Also `k[0][0]` should be printing the whole first word in the tuple e.g. `'projectmanager'` instead of the first character of the first tuple word. What am I missing in understanding what `k[0][0]` means and what it is doing?

Comment: Could you confirm that the second block of code is correct and indented properly

Comment: `k` is the key, if that's a string then `k[0]` is the first character, a string of length 1. So `k[0][0]` is that first character **again**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I think about it `k[0][0]` in my mind means get me the first element of the dictionary then the first sub element.

No, `k` is the key of a given key-value pair. You are iterating over the items, which are those pairs:

```
for k,v in Team.items():
```

Each key-value pair is assigned to the names `k` and `v` there.

Given that you have two different types of keys in your dictionary, strings and tuples, your `type()` information shows you exactly that; you print a series of `<class 'str'>` and `<class 'type'>` for those keys.

So if `k` is a tuple, then `k[0]` is the first element in that tuple and `k[0][0]` is the first character of that first element:

```
>>> k = ('projectmanager', 'Asma')
>>> type(k)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> k[0]
'projectmanager'
>>> k[0][0]
'p'
```

For strings, `k[0]` would be the first character. But a single character is a *string too*. A string of length 1, so getting the first element of that string is **still a string**, again of length 1:

```
>>> k = 'developer1'
>>> type(k)
<class 'str'>
>>> k[0]
'd'
>>> type(k[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> len(k[0])
1
>>> k[0][0]
'd'
```

You wouldn't get an empty value here.

Comment: Brilliant, that really helps me understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,
First case- key, k is set to be a to be tuple. For instance ('projectmanager','Asma'). Hence obviously k[0][0] will print out p

Second case (the more tricky one) when k is set to be a string, k[0] is the first element of string. k[0] is hence a string of length 1. Doing
k[0][0] would access the first element of k[0] which is inturn the same as k[0] is a string of length 1.For example when `k`  is `'developer1'` ,`k[0]` is`'d'` and `k[0][0]`  is hence `'d'`

Hope this helps, good luck